# Zend_Form and setElementFilters with Zend_Filter_StringTrim does not trim

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-filter

PHP Code:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$filters = array(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim());
$form->setElementFilters($filters); // <-- ISSUE

$customerName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('customer_name');
$customerName->setRequired();
$form->addElement($customerName);

$data = $this->_getAllParams();
if ($form->isValid($data)) {
    var_dump($form->getValue('customer_name'));
    // Should be "Testing Trim"
    // Actual result is " Testing Trim "
} else {
    exit('Failed');
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" value=" Testing Trim " />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Has anyone come across this issue and if so how do you fix it globaly for the setElementFilters method?

If I add the filter to the element it works fine. I just don't want to set the trim for each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're setting filters before the element has actually been added to the form. Try changing the order, first add the element, then set filters:

```
$form->addElement($customerName);    
$form->setElementFilters($filters);
```

Comment: Thanks Vika. That worked. You would think that it should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $form->setElementFilters(array('StringTrim'));
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't not make a difference. Thanks though.